# Why are water heaters generally installed on a pedestal?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, safety

Why are tank-style water heaters generally installed on a 2-3 foot (~0.6-0.7 meter) tall pedestal?

Comment: I'm self-closing as a duplicate.  Most of the answers to the other question don't answer this one, but one may.  If that answer is correct, the reason is to elevate the source of ignition to a level high enough that it reduces the chance of igniting flammable gases that may be in the area.

Comment: If your water heater is located in a garage, since gasoline fumes sink, raising it off the floor makes really good sense. If it is in a basement with a floor drain then raising it makes no sense at all. Otherwise, it is a "fielder's choice".